# How can I impose a maximum length of the logger message before an automatic line wrap?

Tags: python, logging, python-logging

I am currently working with the python logging library. In some cases my error messages are quite long. I would like to be able to define an automatic line break from 120 characters for example. Is it possible ?

exemple :

I currently have this :
INFO - my message is toooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo long
I would have this :
INFO - my message is tooooooooooooooooo
ooooooooooooooooooo long

Thanks in advance for your help.

Pierre.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the logging library directly supports this. However, there are a few options.

1. Use the [textwrap](https://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html) module to manually format your log lines before emitting lines.
2. Don't do anything and let the screen on which you're viewing it take care of text wrapping. This might be better especially if you need to cut/paste lines in entirety.

Answer (score 0):

You can impose a maximum length of the logger message before an automatic line wrap using the logging library in Python. You can achieve this by adding a custom formatter to the logging module, which formats the log message with a line break when the maximum length is exceeded.

Look at the example below:

```
import logging

class MaxLengthFormatter(logging.Formatter):
    def __init__(self, max_length=120):
        super().__init__()
        self.max_length = max_length

    def format(self, record):
        msg = super().format(record)
        if len(msg) > self.max_length:
            lines = []
            while len(msg) > self.max_length:
                lines.append(msg[:self.max_length])
                msg = msg[self.max_length:]
            lines.append(msg)
            return '\n'.join(lines)
        else:
            return msg

logger = logging.getLogger('example')
handler = logging.StreamHandler()
formatter = MaxLengthFormatter()
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(handler)

logger.info('my message is toooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo long')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example, based on @Noufal Ibrahim suggestion to use the `textwrap` module.

```
import logging
from textwrap import wrap


class MultiLineHandler(logging.StreamHandler):
    def __init__(self, line_length: int):
        logging.StreamHandler.__init__(self)
        self.line_length = line_length

    def emit(self, record):
        record.msg = "\n".join(wrap(record.msg, self.line_length))
        super().emit(record)


logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
logger.addHandler(MultiLineHandler(line_length=80))
for handler in logger.handlers:
    handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter("%(levelname)s - %(message)s"))
```

Output:

```
INFO - this is a short message
INFO - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus purus augue,
maximus id pharetra in, pellentesque nec felis. Vestibulum posuere velit mi, nec
scelerisque justo vehicula et. Praesent iaculis arcu quis dui facilisis, et
venenatis nibh hendrerit. Integer lobortis nisi nulla, et hendrerit eros iaculis
vitae. Phasellus tortor lectus, fringilla interdum ornare nec, venenatis id
metus.
```